# mvn package of spring boot application with resource, always repackage the entire application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, package

Running "mvn package" on a spring boot application with resources dir, does always repackage the entire module even if no modification to the source code have been made.

To reproduce this problem run these instructions:

- git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git
- cd gs-spring-boot/initial
- mvn package
- ls -l --time-style='+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' target/*.jar

  - -rw-rw-r-- 1 mario mario 16224690 08-02-2019 00:19:37 target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
- mvn package
- ls -l --time-style='+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' target/*.jar

  - -rw-rw-r-- 1 mario mario 16224690 08-02-2019 00:19:37 target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar (same date: OK)

Now add a resource directory and a application.properties file:

- mkdir src/main/resources
- touch src/main/resources/application.properties

and rerun the test:

- mvn package
- ls -l --time-style='+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' target/*.jar

  - -rw-rw-r-- 1 mario mario 16225034 08-02-2019 00:29:09 target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
- Wait some seconds
- mvn package
- ls -l --time-style='+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' target/*.jar

  - -rw-rw-r-- 1 mario mario 16225034 08-02-2019 00:29:43 target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar (NOK)

The Maven output is this:

```
mario@PRS-NB-005# mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gs-spring-boot 0.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ gs-spring-boot ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ gs-spring-boot ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ gs-spring-boot ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /mario/prj/web/bbb/gs-spring-boot/initial/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gs-spring-boot ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ gs-spring-boot ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ gs-spring-boot ---
[INFO] Building jar: /mario/prj/web/bbb/gs-spring-boot/initial/target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ gs-spring-boot ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.337 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-08T00:29:43+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/308M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the effective pom.
There you will see the following:

```
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>path/gs-spring-boot/initial/src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/application*.yml</include>
                <include>**/application*.yaml</include>
                <include>**/application*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
       ...
```

Because of the `<filtering>true</filtering>` it creates the jar with each `mvn package`.

This configuration comes from:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

If you do not need the filtering for your application.properties you can override in the pom.xml from initial.